# using function parameters in assembly after pushing registers (pusha saving state)

Tags: function, assembly, parameters, parameter-passing, tasm

From what I understand (correct me if I'm mistaken), I can do the following:

```
push param3
push param2
push param1
call func1
```

and then inside `func1` I can access these params by doing this:

```
proc func1:
    push bp
    
    mov bp, sp

    mov ax, [bp+8] ; param1
    mov ax, [bp+6] ; param2
    mov ax, [bp+4] ; param3

endp
```

But what if instead of `push`ing just `bp`, I would've pushed more registers? or used `pusha`? how would this effect the parameter accessing. What is the logic behind this when looking at the stack?

Comment: It would obviously put the stack args higher above `sp` if you did more pushes before `mov bp, sp`.  That's why it's normal *not* to do that, defeating part of the purpose of having a standardized frame-pointer.  Also, your comments are backwards in `func1`: `param1` is at the lowest address because you pushed it last.

Comment: @PeterCordes so I should first save `bp`, then `mov bp, sp`, and then save the rest of the registers if I want to? And what is the logic of the param accessing I show in my example? why do we push param3 first and why do we access it with `bp+4` and not `bp` or `bp+8`?

Comment: Yup, that's the standard stack-frame layout, which creates a linked list of frame pointers for debuggers to unwind, as well as always making the first stack arg at `[bp+4]` (in near-call functions).  Of course, passing args in registers is even more efficient; a good calling convention has a mix of call-preserved and call-clobbered registers so functions can use some without saving/restoring at all.

Comment: Pushing args right-to-left is standard for C calling conventions, so the first arg is at a known spot.  This supports variadic functions like `printf`.  As for why the args are where they are, follow the stack layout in your head or on paper, or while single-stepping in a debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes but the stack grows downwards, right? so when I push param1 last, it should have the smallest address, doesn't it? Also, why do the parameters start from `+4`? what is pushed to the stack? I guess my question is what does the stack look like after the call

Comment: @PeterCordes if I push param3, and then param2 and then param1, isn't the [following image](https://pasteboard.co/1E5hPqoIG9FQ.png) correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, unlike the comments in your question where you have `[bp+8] ; param1`, reversed order.

Comment: @PeterCordes So my comments are mistaken is what you're saying, but the analysis in the image is correct

Comment: 16bit Standard calling convention which uses PUSHA is better illustrated by the image at  https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/stdcal16.htm